# “Permission denied” in IE 8 and 7 using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jquery plugin. this working fine in chrome, Mozilla and IE 9 but in IE 8/7 I am getting Permission denied error on line "$ctxObj.control2.val(opt.topicDefaultText);"

[image: IE console]

```
Test.Plugin = function () {
var $ctxObj = {};
var opt = {};
var initEvents = function() {

    $ctxObj.control2.val(opt.topicDefaultText);

    $ctxObj.control2.on('click', function (e) {
        somefunction();
    });

    $ctxObj.control1.on('click',function(){
 anotherfunction();
    });
};
return {
    init: function (options) {
        var defaultOptions = {
            control1: '#control1',
            control2: '#control2',
            topicDefaultText:'test'
        };
        opt = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
        $ctxObj.control1 = $(opt.control1);
        $ctxObj.control2 = $(opt.control2);
        initEvents();
    }
};
```

} ();

if I declare a variable for each control like below:

var $control1 =$('#control1');

var $control2 =$('#control2');

and then using code

```
   $control2.val(opt.topicDefaultText);

    $control2.on('click', function (e) {
        somefunction();
    });

    $control1.on('click',function(){
      anotherfunction();
    });
```

using above code I am not getting any error in IE but as in this plugin I have so many controls so I don't want to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all object-properties are set and that you actually have permission to access them.

Answer (score 0):

IE has a big problem with jQuery. My IE9 always tells me to enable ActiveX controls when I'm testing jQuery on it. Try telling your IE users to enable ActiveX Controls.